# Header has extra HTML block at top before my code

Tags: php, html, wp-head

I've been trying to fix the issue where wp_head loads in the body tag in wordpress, and I've discovered that when I look at the page source, an extra HTML block appears before the code from my header.php file.

Here's what I've tried:

1. Setting wp_debug to true
2. ensuring that charset is UTF-8
3. removing all text before the beginning of !DOCTYPE
4. check for missing closing tags

This is my `header.php` file
[image]

Here is the output source:
[image: You can see that my code is being rendered correctly.. but why am I getting a HTML block at the start of the document??]

You can see that my code is being rendered correctly.. but why am I getting a HTML block at the start of the document?? Any help would be amazing. Thanks so much

Comment: @Abhik the header.php is the content in the first screenshot.

Comment: Can't see any odd in your code. Try moving the `wp_head()` call to before closing `<head>` tag.

Comment: That didn't work... but thanks for the suggestion @Abhik

Comment: There's most likely some static HTML somewhere in your template files. copy your themes files to your computer, and search for the `<title>Document</title>` as text among the files. You'll probably find where it's being added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am really not sure what's causing this. Can you try with a minimal content in `header.php`? Something like this and see if the problem occurs?

```
<!doctype html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

And, meta tags doesn't support `class` attributes like you have in line 11.

Comment: thanks for the advice, i removed the meta class from the head and relocated the `wp_head()` to the bottom and it started to work correctly. Thanks for your help